# Cannot repair disk0s2 with mavericks utility disk on a SSD

Tags: startup, ssd, disk-utility, partition, error

I was trying to repair a corrupted partition (OSX Mavericks) the mac doesn't boot anymore (grey apple logo with infinty spinning gear). I've just tried with **safe mode**, **PRAM restor** etc... And the recovery HD partition doesn't boot the UD so I had to create a bootable USB mavericks installation and start there the UD.

When i run, from terminal: *diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk0s2* it return an error of **bad ref** of that file system with this **code -69846**. after that i can't see anymore the disk0 through *diskutil list*. also, I cannot erase the partition because it appears unmounted (light grey text on the HD list)

I've tried also to start an install of mavericks directly but it doesn't show me the SSD to locate the installation.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have booted from other media and tried Apple's tools then the only thing(s) left are 3rd party tools.

My go-to is Diskwarrior and while some drives with a **lot** of files will cause it to fail (so I have heard) I've, personally, never had an issue with it. It has always worked and almost always fixed the problem.

Failing that TechTool pro and Prosoft Engineering are a couple of other places to look.